# How to clear a function after particular amount of time

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I have a function which keeps on executing i want that whole function(function main())to stop working after 3secs and it has to call another function

```
$(function main() {
$( "#button" ).click(function() {
  $( "#effect" ).addClass( "newClass", callback );
});
function up() {
setTimeout(function() {
  $( "#effect" ).addClass( "newClass", callback );
},1000);  
}
function callback() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $( "#effect" ).addClass( "down" ,up).removeClass('newClass');
  }, 1000 );
}
});
```

Comment: `addClass` accepts only one argument...

Answer (score 0):

In j query there is unbind function for unbind the event for html element following syntax

```
$(selector).unbind(event,function,eventObj)
```

Follow following code in your case. it will unbind click event of button after 3 sec.

```
setTimeout(function(){
$("#button").unbind("click");
}, 3000)
```

Comment: ya anurag What if i start function on page starts istead of button click?

Comment: it will unbind click event of button after 3 sec